# Angular close modals for 401 response

Tags: angular, jwt, modal-dialog, ng-bootstrap

I am using the following code to redirect a user to the login page if the response from server has a status of 401 or 403.

```
return this.http
        .request(this.method, this.prepareUrl(url), options)
        .pipe(
            catchError((error: HttpErrorResponse) => {
                if ([401, 403].includes(error.status)) {
                   this.router.navigate(['/login']);
                }
                const err: Errors = {
                    error: error,
                    formError: error.error.data.validation ? error.error.data.validation : null
                };

                return Observable.throw(err);
            })
        );
```

This is working fine. But when used with modal popups and if the token has been expired, it is showing navigating to the login page, but the modal is still there. How can I prevent this and close the modal if the response status is 401 ? I am using ngBootstrap modals.

Or is it a good practice to prevent the user from opening modal if the token is not valid ? If so, how can I verify it from a central place as I have a number of modals

Answer (score 1):

You can leverage the method `NgbModal.dismissAll(reason)`

```
export MyComponent {
   constructor(protected ngbModal:NgbModal){}

   public myMethod() {
      return this.http
        .request(this.method, this.prepareUrl(url), options)
        .pipe(
            catchError((error: HttpErrorResponse) => {
                if ([401, 403].includes(error.status)) {
                   this.ngbModal.dismissAll('Unauthorized');
                   this.router.navigate(['/login']);
                }
                const err: Errors = {
                    error: error,
                    formError: error.error.data.validation ? error.error.data.validation : null
                };

                return Observable.throw(err);
            })
        );
   }
}
```

It could be a good idea to use [Http interceptor](https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpInterceptor) to handle the responses globally.

Considering is it a good practice. It would be a good user experience to restore the app state (values in the form fields, currently opened modals, accordion state, etc) after the authentication. With redirects it's quite hard. The modal with authentication form could be an easier to implement solution.

It depends much on your app thought.